# Write to subdirectory using freopen

Tags: c, freopen

I am trying to write out to files inside subdirectories using freopen:

`freopen("output/output-1.txt", "w", stdout);`

I have tried changing it to output to the current directory and it works. It terminates without errors when the target output file is in a subdirectory; however no files are created. Creating the required directory does not fix the issue.

```
void write_to(int subtask, int tc){
    string output = string("testcases/subtask-") + to_string(subtask) + "-tc-" + to_string(tc);
    freopen(output.c_str(), "w", stdout);
}

int main(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 25; i++){
        write_to(1, i);
        // rest of code to generate and cout test cases
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: the path spec is relative to the current directory of the execution not to the directory the executable is in.

Comment: Does the `output` directory already exist ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes it already exists

Comment: @jerry outputting to the absolute path also does not work

Comment: `"stdout"`? Are you compiling with warnings?

Comment: Do not quote `stdout`.  That gives you a string, whereas you need a `FILE *`.  The resulting behavior is undefined.

Comment: @FanPu 1) show more relevant code, 2) show how you run your program. 3) What exactly do you mean by "execution directory" ?

Comment: Do present a [mcve].  Without one we are left guessing at what the real problem might be, and you have already rejected all the most likely guesses.

Comment: Test the result of `freopen` because it can fail (and then gives `NULL`)

Comment: BTW, standard C99 or C11 does not know about directories. I guess that you are coding for POSIX standard, or even on some Linux system. Then you should tag your question appropriately (e.g. if on Linux, add the `Linux` tag). On Linux you might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to figure out what system calls are executed.

Comment: Use [`getcwd`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) to printf the current directory right at the beginning of `main`, which may help to find out what is going on.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation of [freopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html). You should test and use its result:

> The `freopen()` function opens the file whose name is the string
>     pointed to by `path` and associates the stream pointed to by stream
>     with it.  **The original stream (if it exists) is closed.**

about its return value:

> Upon successful completion `fopen()`, `fdopen()` and `freopen()` return a
>          FILE pointer.  *Otherwise*, `NULL` is returned and `errno` is set to
>          indicate the error.

So you need to code at least (if on Linux or some POSIX system)

```
void write_to(int subtask, int tc){
   string output = 
     string("testcases/subtask-") + to_string(subtask) 
      + "-tc-" + to_string(tc);
   FILE*outf = freopen(output.c_str(), "w", stdout);
   if (!outf) {
     perror(output.c_str());
     char pwdbuf[128];
     memset (pwdbuf, 0, sizeof(pwdbuf));
     getcwd(pwdbuf, sizeof(pwdbuf)-1);
     fprintf(stderr, "failure in %s\n", pwdbuf);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

<sup>(the code above won't solve your issue, but will output a meaningful error message on error; perhaps you are not running your code in the appropriate current directory)</sup>

I also recommend ending your `for` loop in `main` with `fflush(stdout)` or `fflush(NULL)`.

If on Linux or POSIX, you might instead work at the file descriptor level (so code a redirection), and use [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) & [dup(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) (using `STDOUT_FILENO` as the second argument to `dup2`).

If `testcases` is a directory in your `$HOME` (that is, `~/testcases/` as expanded by your shell) you would want

```
string output =
  string (getenv("HOME")) + "/" 
  + string("testcases/subtask-") + to_string(subtask) 
  + "-tc-" + to_string(tc);
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. The error was Permission Denied - executing as root allowed the files to be created in subdirectories.

Comment: You should never execute as root a program that you wrote, unless you are sure to not have any security hole.